# OCTAVE- Create a FIGURE where to put interactive SLIDERS, that changes parameters of my plot (drawn in another figure)

Tags: matlab, slider, octave

I need to create sliders near my plot, interacting with its parameters. 
Can someone explain me how create it in the same figure, put name and value of the slider parameter close to it and how to link it with my plot?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a GUI - does octave have a 'GUIDE' functionality?

Answer (score 3):

have a look at [demo_uicontrol.m](https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/demo_uicontrol.m) which has all you need:

[image: demo_uicontrol screenshot]

A stripped example for what you've asked "sliders near my plot"

```
## Useful since Octave 4.0

close all
clear h

graphics_toolkit qt

h.ax = axes ("position", [0.05 0.42 0.5 0.5]);

function update_plot (obj, init = false)

  ## gcbo holds the handle of the control
  h = guidata (obj);

  a = get (h.slider1, "value");
  w = get (h.slider2, "value");
  x = linspace (0, 3);
  y = a * sin (x * 5 * w);

  if (init)
    h.plot = plot (x, y, "b");
  else
    set (h.plot, "xdata", x);
    set (h.plot, "ydata", y);
  endif
  guidata (obj, h);

endfunction

h.slider1 = uicontrol ("style", "slider",
                      "units", "normalized",
                      "string", "slider",
                      "callback", @update_plot,
                      "value", 0.4,
                      "position", [0.05 0.25 0.35 0.06]);

h.slider2 = uicontrol ("style", "slider",
                      "units", "normalized",
                      "string", "slider",
                      "callback", @update_plot,
                      "value", 0.7,
                      "position", [0.05 0.15 0.35 0.06]);

set (gcf, "color", get(0, "defaultuicontrolbackgroundcolor"))
guidata (gcf, h)
update_plot (gcf, true);
```

[image: demo2]